# How to visualize MBTiles with OpenLayers using a PHP tile server?

Tags: openlayers-2, php, mbtiles

This is repost as didn't get my expected answer. Please help me as I am newbie.

I have setup the PHP Tile Server 0.1 and when I am calling the PHP server it showing the following[image]

Now I am triyng to visualize the map using openlayers. I am using the following code. I am just in the beginning stage so small mistakes may be really easy to me.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
      <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var TMS = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "MBTiles Overlay",
            "http://localhost:8080/tileserver/DHK_17/", {layers: 'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(TMS);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(23.81, 90.40),17);
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am struggling from last night. Please help me.

Comment: and what is your problem exactly?

Comment: The script is not showing maps of mbtiles. Its showing blank/pink tiles only. I used only 16,17 &18 zoom data of Bangladesh